# (MySQL and .Net Core) select query which has runtime value in where clause not working

Tags: mysql, .net-core

**Implementation**

To fetch `attendance` by `student symbol number`.

**Code**

Hard coding the `symbolnumber` works but with the `runtime` value the code does not work.

> string query = $"select * from attendance where symbolnumber=1111;";  This works
>
> string query = $"select * from attendance where symbolnumber={symbolnumber};";    This does not work

```
  using (MySqlConnection conn = GetConnection())
        {
            conn.Open();
            string query = $"select * from attendance where symbolnumber={symbolnumber};"; -> This does not work
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);

            using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    list.Add(new Attendance()
                    {
                        SymbolNumber = reader.GetInt64("symbolnumber"),
                        AttendanceDate = reader.GetDateTime("attendancedate"),
                        IsPresent = reader.GetBoolean("ispresent"),
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

**FYI**

There is no error or exception and there is no spelling mistake in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a prepared statement here:

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = GetConnection())
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE symbolnumber = @symbolnumber";
    cmd.Prepare();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@symbolnumber", 1111);

    // retrieve results here
}
```